# Check Python version in package __init__.py containing newer syntax

Tags: python

Checking Python version in my program is generally no problem, but how to generally do it if syntax is used, which the old interpreter does not know of?

Consider the following `__init__.py` in a sub-directory/package `foo`:

```
import sys

__version__ = '0.1'

try:
    if sys.version_info[:2] < (3,8):
        print("you're doomed")
    else:
        print("you're fine")

    print(f"{__version__=}")
    
except SyntaxError:
    print("why is this line not reached on importing?")

print("here we go")
```

Now, when trying to import that package, a SyntaxError appears:

```
$ python3
Python 3.7.7 (default, Apr  1 2020, 13:48:52) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<fstring>", line 1
    (__version__=)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

or with direct usage:

```
$ python3 foo/__init__.py                                                                                       /dev/shm |myself@mydesk|0|11:53:43 
  File "<fstring>", line 1
    (__version__=)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Although I tried to catch the exception (which is of course not possible for SyntaxError without some `eval` around the according line), Python won't even run the file if the interpreter version is below 3.8, because [the new f-string '`=`' specifier](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging) is used. (In this minimal example one could of cause suggest to just leave it away, but in my real package it is used at many places, including many sub-packages's __init__.py; especially to ease logging.)

So how can we ensure the correct minimum Python version in scenarios like that, which use new syntax, including a warning message for the users?

Comment: You can't - none of the code in that file will be run, because it can't successfully be parsed.

Comment: Or, if you **really** must use a syntax that is broken in past python to do something using the latest and newest syntax possible, put the failing code in a string and then call `exec` with it, e.g. `exec('print(f"{__version__=}")')`.  This will allow the interpreter to parse the code successfully, then also trigger the `SyntaxError` when the interpreter tries to execute that string as Python code.

Comment: @metatoaster: that would mean to do this on every 3.8 f-string you ever want to use in some logging entry in \_\_init__ files, which is not really better than leaving a feature away completely. And as I am searching for a general way for scenarios like the one described (edited question a bit to highlight that), not only for f-string usage, it would not really help out either.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve? Ensuring that a package is only used for the correct Python version is generally a task of the packaging tool/metadata (e.g. pip), not the package itself.

Comment: @Jaleks By definition there is *no* general way when the syntax itself is failing at the basic level.  This is like the reintroduction of the `u` prefixed strings in Python 3.3 that previous Python 3 has lacked. A Python 3.3 package that wishes to also bring similar unicode support to Python 2.7 will have to make use of the `u` prefixed to ensure `unicode` types being used (and this will break Python 3.2).  This is a drawback you need to accept, and have the package manager deal with installing the correct version of your package for the Python at hand.

Comment: @metatoaster: Thx for clarifying. If you provide it as answer, I'll be happy to accept it, for you gaining the repu points :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the brief discussion via the comments, it was clarified that the goal was to make use of the latest syntax as much as possible, and satisfy that:

- Include instructions (code) within that given module such that when it is imported, it will execute to provide a warning to its user that a `SyntaxError` will be encountered.
- Achieve all this without an indirection module.

Unfortunately, doing all this together is effectively impossible.  Python has to first parse the entire source file *successfully* before it can execute *any* instructions.  In other words, syntax that cause the parsing to fail with a `SyntaxError` will simply result in none of the code in the source file being turned into byte-code instructions that may be executed.

This type of change is not without precedence - Python 3 originally redefined the syntax for the `str` tokens to not accept a `u` prefix (e.g. `u'Hello'`).  Then Python 3.3 came along and (re)introduced that syntax (from Python 2.7) as part of the effort to make it easier for library developers to migrate their code from Python 2 to Python 3, this meant that Python modules that include this `u` prefix strings will not work for Python 3.2, but will work for Python 3.3.

Given that the mere existence of `u` prefix in a single string in a given Python file will break Python 3.2, there was no mitigation possible barring the removal of all `u` prefixes in the source file before any code (including version detection).  The situation is not unlike your desire to make use of the new f-string syntax for logging.

As @MisterMiyagi pointed out, version management for a module is part of the "meta", or the management of the environment, so this should be something that is not managed from within the module at runtime, but rather it should be dealt at the environment level.  Python packaging utilities such as `pip` will correctly prevent the installation of a module marked with a Python version beyond what is currently in-use, which should be the manner which this is done.

For other situations not to do with syntax, such as changes to import locations of the standard library, this can be trapped in a similar manner like in the question itself - as the code was correctly parsed, the `try...except` block can be turned into the bytecode instructions that can then be executed.

Alternatively, an indirection module import like the one suggested by the answer @AKX provided may be used, should that syntax issue is not prevalent enough to prevent the possibility of that approach.  However this would raise the question of how to deal with the fallback, but this again goes back to putting the problem back into the correct domain which it should be solved it (i.e. package management).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution I can think of is to not put version-specific syntax in `__init__.py` to ensure it can always be parsed.

```
import sys

__version__ = '0.1'

if sys.version_info[:2] < (3,8):
    raise RuntimeError("You're doomed.")

from .baz import quux
from .hernekeitto import teline
```

This file can always be parsed and executed with... basically any Python from 2.7 up, and since imports are runtime, the program would only start crashing once `baz.py` and `hernekeitto.py` use esoteric syntax.

Comment: Not using new Python syntax in any __init__ file over years, in the whole package tree, is not really a feasible option, in my eyes.That would also include not being able to use any `foo.my_something` in the whole package, if that uses new syntax, including messing up the api-doc.

Comment: I'm not following what you mean with "not being able to use..." (sorry for terseness, on mobile)